# update choropleth by string (not by fillKey prop)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, choropleth, datamaps

I read the guide->updating after initial drawing part at https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps but updating doesn't work using string values (it works fine using fillKey property instead). I read this closed issue too: markmarkoh/datamaps#118 but nothing.

This is my code:

```
v

ar map = new Datamap({
    element: document.getElementById('world'),          
    geographyConfig: {
      dataUrl: 'world-topo-min.json',
      borderColor: 'black'
     },
     scope: 'countries',        
     fills: {
       defaultFill: 'rgb(255,255,255)',     
       someKey: '#08306b'
     },
    data: {
      '108': {fillKey: 'someKey'}               
    },
    setProjection: function(element) {
      var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
        .center([30, 34.4444])
        .scale(170)
        .translate([element.offsetWidth / 2 , element.offsetHeight/2]);

       var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
       return {path: path, projection: projection};
    }
  });map.updateChoropleth({'57': {fillKey:'someKey'},'116': '#08306b'});
```

Country identificated by id=57 is ok, country 116 doesn't change

I pull data from a PHP-array like this:
myarray=[[57,32],[116,12]]
Country 57 has value 32, country 116 has value 12 and so on.
I ignore myarray right now because I want to solve updatechoropleth issue first
Obviously, I'm going to create a linear scale to put right colors into countries path but this is another thing.

Help me please
Thank you guys!

Comment: Do you have a link to this running? I verified election.updateChoropleth({"NY": "#08306b", "TX": {fillKey: "Democrat"}}); works fine on the DataMaps website, so I think the issue is with your TopoJSON.

Comment: I made topojson starting from shp then converted to json with mapsharer.org. Below the link to my topojson       http://we.tl/v1EJcyvDJh

Comment: @markmarkoh Thank you for advice. Assuming my topojson is wrong, I just loaded 3 scripts: a) cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js------b)cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js--------c)datamaps.world.min.js               The scope is 'world' now and no other dataUrl is selected. Probably my page load 'standard library' with basic property now, am I right? Copy&Paste from [link]https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps#updating-a-choropleth-after-initial-drawing  map.updateChoropleth({
   USA: {fillKey: 'LOW'},
   CAN: '#0fa0fa'
}); but nothing